Udev not triggering a new process upon event trigger
I don't know if I'm checking the details incorrectly or something.
I have a udev rule that triggers some_process.service.
I see the logs through sudo journalctl -u some_process.service
When i trigger the udev the first time i see the logs for some_process.service start up. This process takes a couple of minutes to complete. So if i trigger the udev rule again within those couple of minutes, it doesn't look like it re-runs some_process.service. The older version of the process continues on. Shouldn't the udev trigger a new run? How do i get it to trigger a new run ?

Not that I ever tried anything like this, but I would guess it depends on what your service file looks like (e.g. run only once?).
